# When querying database is it possible to remove repetitive data fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a general collection **recipes** where I hold all recipes in my database.

Now, because I am trying to provide more tailored recipes for each user, I have multiple variations of the same recipe(mostly same ingredients but different quantities).

Let's say user searches for "Jerk chicken" recipes over 400 calories and I have these 3 documents - 2 of them have the same **parentID** meaning it's the same recipe and I don't want to display it numerous times.

```
  {name: "Jerk with rice", ingredients: {}, calories: 400, parentId: 234 }
  {name: "Jerk with rice", ingredients: {}, calories: 410, parentId: 234 }
  {name: "Jerk with rice", ingredients: {}, calories: 410, parentId: 200 }
```

Is there a way that I could make a query from a backend that *"if an item with the same parentID has been queried, don't request it again"*

I know that I can use **.limit(1)** but that would only get me 1 of the 2 recipes that I have.

I thought about making original recipes collection, and store variations in a subcollection, but I don't know if that could work either.

Comment: This question needs more info about your data store.

Comment: it's just Recipes collection and every document is a different recipe, or is there any other info that you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot the database can do here. The `parentID` is pure application logic, and I don't see a way to catch your "where the parentID is not in the result set" in a query.

You could consider changing the data model to allow the query, but it sounds like what you want is going to be quite dynamic and it'll probably remain beyond Firestore's querying capabilities. If such searches are a use-case for your app, consider using a dedicated search engine, such as [Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).